# ASP.NET MVC get action result / activity from embedded site (external site)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, embed, activiti

Is it possible to get the activity action (e.g. press search/save button) from an embedded site?

I want to use activiti bpm to my mvc project (activiti doesn't have ui integration).

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. if you're using e.g. an iframe, this happens at client side so you could be using Javascript or jQuery to get the content. If you have control of the site, you can create an api to retrieve the content. If the web site is third party, you could scrape the content by using web scraping library or an automated tool.

Comment: Hi @Clifford most likely on using iframe since i don't have direct access to activiti since it is written in java springboot. I also found some suggestions using jQuery to capture the action behavior of the third party site.

You mentioned automated tool, could you provide sample of that?

Thank you for your help and assistance.

Comment: I mean automated tools like Selenium can be used for web scraping if the web site does not provide an api. Another option is the WebBrowser class included in .Net Framework. Apart from that I have used open source library HtmlAgilityPack for doing simple stuff.

Comment: @derloopkat thanks for your suggestion.
I'll try to test and use it in my project.
Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @zysirhc Why am I referenced in your comment?

Comment: @Clifford it's for derloopkat, my mistake (can't edit anymore)